# kivy compare to weakref

Tags: python, kivy, weak-references

How do I compare if a kivy weakref points to a given object?

Setup:

```
>>> my_obj
<__main__.Marker object at 0x610054ee8> 

>>> my_list
[<weakref at 0x6100662c8; to 'Marker' at 0x610054ee8>]
```

My list is concretely `touch.grab_list` comming from a kivy touch event and contains weakrefs to all grabbed widgets.

I would like to do something like `if my_obj in my_list:` and get `True` but clearly this returns `False` because the weakref and `my_obj` are different objects.
What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I feel stupid now, just stumbled across the solution.

A weakref returns the object when called. So we can use that and `map`:

```
>>> my_obj in map(lambda x: x(), my_list)
True
```